# Как получить логин в ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Я новичок в мире ASP.NET. Смог сделать авторизацию через логин/пароль.

**AccountViewModels.cs**

```
 public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
...
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
...
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
...
```

Но как мне теперь получить имя, авторизовавшегося пользователя (**UserName**)? К примеру, чтобы затем получить относящиеся к нему записи из базы данных?

Полязив по SO, нашел [тему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739778/get-userid-of-logged-in-user-in-asp-net-mvc-5) и с помощью кода оттуда хотел просто хотя бы вывести **UserName** в консоль:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    if (claimsIdentity != null)
    {
        // the principal identity is a claims identity.
        // now we need to find the NameIdentifier claim
        var userIdClaim = claimsIdentity.Claims
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        if (userIdClaim != null)
        {
            var userIdValue = userIdClaim.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(userIdValue.ToString());
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

Но в консоле так и ничего не появилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В userIdValue храниться **ID**. А мне нужно было свойство UserName, которое храниться в **User.Identity.Name**. После этого обнаружения дальше все конечно же пошло по накатанной. Я передал это имя во View через ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult Index2()
{
    var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    if (claimsIdentity != null)
    {
        var userIdClaim = claimsIdentity.Claims
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        if (userIdClaim != null)
        {
            var userIdValue = userIdClaim.Value;
            ViewBag.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```